# JavaParser: Detect if FieldDeclaration is Interface Type

Tags: java, javaparser

I am gathering class metadata using JavaParser to store in a JSON object. For each compilation unit I collect, I also collect a list of the FieldDeclarations. For each FieldDeclaration, I would like to see if the type is an interface type.

In the java doc I noticed that FieldDeclaration inherits `isClassOrInterfaceDeclaration()` from BodyDeclaration, however I would like something like `isInterfaceDeclaration()`.

I notice, however, that the class `ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration` has a method `isInterface()`. 
Would it be irresponsible to take a `FieldDeclaration f` and do something like:

`Boolean b = f.toClassOrInterfaceDeclaration().isInterface()`

Ultimately I would like to distinguish whether a FieldDeclaration is of a Class type, or Interface type.

Something I have also considered is:

```
Type t = f.getElementType() ;
// Dodgy code ahead
if(t == Class) { // do something...}
```

If someone can point in me in the right direction, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Some exploratory testing I did yielded some unexpected results. I collected a list of Field declarations from a class, the fields are:

```
private String s;
private String addedState ;
// Component is an interface
private Component c ;
```

When performing `isClassOrInterfaceDeclaration()` on each of these fields, each one returned false. But when I performed:

```
f.forEach(n->System.out.println(n.getElementType().isClassOrInterfaceType())) ;
```

each one returned true.

My assumptions about what the expected output would be have been proven false.

Edit 2: I have come to realize why calling isClassOrInterfaceDeclaration() does not yield true, because the fields are literally not declaring a class or interface. I need to find a way to determine if the type is a Class or Interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a Java symbol solver, which is included with JavaParser.

To use it, you have to instantiate the parser a certain way

```
 //The files are jar files that contain types you want to resolve
 static final JavaParser createJavaParser(File... jarFiles) {
      CombinedTypeSolver typeSolver = new CombinedTypeSolver();

      //Allows you to resolve types that comes with the JDK 
      typeSolver.add(new ReflectionTypeSolver());

      // Make it so the parser can recognize types within the jar files
      try {
           for (File jar : jarFiles) {
                typeSolver.add(new JarTypeSolver(jar));
           }
      } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }

      // Create the config for the parser
      JavaSymbolSolver symbolSolver = new JavaSymbolSolver(typeSolver);
      ParserConfiguration parserConfiguration = new ParserConfiguration();
      parserConfiguration.setSymbolResolver(symbolSolver);

      // Construct the parser
      return new JavaParser(parserConfiguration);
 }
```

If a `CompilationUnit` was contructed using a parser from this method, you can then use the following code to determine if the type of a `FieldDeclaration` is an interface type

```
 static final boolean hasInterfaceType(FieldDeclaration f) {
      return f.resolve().declaringType().isInterface();
 }
```